# What is an Iterable in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a bit confused by the difference between `Iterable<int>` and `List<int>`? because sometimes I face `Iterable<SomeObject>` and I don't know why it is used for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Difference part is already answered but why it's used is not. The main reason you want to use iterable is because it's generic.

The only requirement for that object is that it needs to be *iterable* that is, you can iterate on it. With a list you can write a for loop to iterate, for map you can go over it's keys and do something on the values, the function doesn't care how. The only thing it cares for is the ability of going through all the values.

Answer (score 1):

What i found is:

> An Iterable is a collection of elements that can be accessed sequentially, and you can’t instantiate it directly.

The main difference between list and Iterable is:

> That with the Iterable, you can’t guarantee that reading elements by index will be efficient. Iterable, as opposed to List, doesn’t have the [] operator.

Src:

[dart.dev/codelabs/iterables](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)